# Finding a missed row in time series in R

Tags: r

I have a daily time series for 20 years(column 1 dates and other columns different data), and one row is deleted, which I don't know which one is.
I want to find that row and insert related date in that row and also interpolate other columns for that row!
Is it possible in R?
Thanks

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your date column is of class "Date", here's a way:

```
# generate sample data
my.df <- data.frame(date=Sys.Date(), other=rnorm(1))
for(i in 2:100) {
  my.df[i,] <- list(Sys.Date() + (i-1), rnorm(1))
}

class(my.df$date)
# [1] "Date"

# remove row 71
my.df <- my.df[-71,]

# Iterate to see where there is a gap
for(i in 2:nrow(my.df)) {
  if(my.df$date[i] != my.df$date[i-1] + 1) {
    cat("missing row:", i)
    break
  }
}
missing row: 71
```